# Soundboard with classes that need rectangles in different location

Tags: java, image, class, processing

So I'm making a sound board with a class and I am trying to make multiple rectangles on the screen with the code i used in the class however, it wont show different locations for each rectangle. can anyone help me? tell me which direction that i need to go.
heres the code

```
        void setup()
{
  size(451,385);
  minim = new Minim(this);
  player = minim.loadFile("deadmau5.mp3");

 soundboard =loadImage("sb.png");
  sound1 = new sound(1,1);
  sound2 = new sound(100,500);
  sound3 = new sound(100,400);
  sound4 = new sound(100,300);
  sound5 = new sound(100,200);
  sound6 = new sound(100,400);
  sound7 = new sound(100,900);
  sound8 = new sound(100,700);
  sound9 = new sound(100,400);
}

void draw()
{
  image(soundboard,1,CENTER);
  sound1.run();
  sound2.run();
}

class sound
{

  float x;
  float y;

  public sound(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  } 




  void run()
{
draw();

}

void draw(){
 rect(x,y,136,133);
    fill(100,10,10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `draw()` function inside your `Sound` class:

```
  void draw() {
    rect(1, 1, 136, 133);
    fill(100, 10, 10);
  }
```

Notice that you're drawing a rectangle at hard-coded coordinates. You probably meant to use different values for each instance, probably the `x` and `y` variables in the `Sound` class?

```
rect(x, y, 136, 133);
```

But your code has a few other problems. When you create your `Sound` instances, you aren't passing in the necessary parameters, so this won't even compile.

Here's a little example that passes in parameters to draw two instances at two different locations:

```
Sound soundOne;
Sound soundTwo;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  soundOne = new Sound(10, 10);
  soundTwo = new Sound(100, 100);
}

void draw() {
  soundOne.draw();
  soundTwo.draw();
}

class Sound {

  float x;
  float y;

  public Sound(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  void draw() {
    rect(x, y, 50, 50);
  }
}
```

Notice that I haven't included any minim code, since your question doesn't have anything to do with minim. Instead of posting your whole sketch, try to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Including extra code that's not related to your problem just makes it harder for us to help you.

Comment: thanks for the help sir, and noted. I wont post the whole code next time

Comment: I used the code you added into the sound class, however it doesn't post 9 different rectangles, I thought it would as we have used 9 sound sound1-9

Comment: @user3318928 Please post your updated code as a [mcve]. But notice that you have to give each instance its own position by passing in parameters to the constructor.

Comment: just not understanding why there isn't 9 rectangles.

Comment: or are they just overlaying eachother?

Comment: @antc You're only ever drawing the first two rectangles.